# Distinguish between the images

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a set of thresholded images and need to be able to distinguish between them. Have tried HoughLines (with morp operation like CLOSE, dilate, erode), does not work consistently in all scenarios. Also prefer to have them separated in a single operation, if possible.

Either 1 & 2 should be classified separately or 3 & 4. While it would be nice, being able to distinguish each type separately would be great.

*Explanation* - For 1 & 2, the contours are fudged (bottom left for #1) together in some or most places. For 3 & 4, the contours stand out separated in most cases.

Any direction would be helpful.

1. [image: Class 1 image]
2. [image: Class 2 image]
3. [image: Class 3 image]
4. [image: Class 4 image]

Comment: This description of the classes is by far insufficient. If you want a blind method, go for deep learning. If you want a basic method, count the fudged balls.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am trying to avoid deep learning/ML in any form due to application constraints.
Having said that, in #1 the fudged balls are connected towards the bottom-left of the image. In #2, they are hardly separable as balls anymore as they appear more like a blob.
For #3 & 4, they are distinguishable more or less as separate balls to the human eye.

I need some approximation/classification without use of ML/training if that is possible.

Comment: The criteria you give are fuzzy and subjective.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I know it is fuzzy since I too am not sure on how to go about it. Will try your idea of counting the fudged balls, that seems like a good alternative to the approach I had found earlier.

Comment: Maybe an important question is to know why precisely you want to classify. If you can't answer that, you will fail.

Comment: To that I have the answer. If we observe that for 1 and 2, the balls are fudged together in certain places. In fact for 2, the balls are not even distinguishable. This is akin to behavior for motion blur in a way.
I need a certain way to differentiate these types for further processing/rejection.

Comment: How do you objectivate "in certain places" ? And "not distinguishable" ? And "akin to behavior for motion blur" ? You need to express that in more concrete terms.

Comment: The core idea is to see if the balls are distinct shapes or not. Under ideal conditions they should represent symmetrical geometric shapes like circle, square, triangle but in real world conditions they will almost never be due to lighting, camera, etc. I also thought of counting the number of balls but they may vary, hence not usable.
Contour area - For perfect balls they always fall within a range (even though the count may be different). When multiple balls are fudged together, the area will be higher than threshold values.
Thanks for keeping the questions coming.